# React shouldComponentUpdate returns true when the props has a function or method call

Tags: reactjs

Please help me understand why `shouldComponentUpdate()` `in Person.js` returns `true` when the `props` I am passing to it has a method from `App.js` even though that method did not change at all.

This is the code from my `App.js`

```
return <Person 
            name={cur.name} 
            age={cur.age} 
            job={cur.job} 
            key={cur.id} 
            change={(event) => this.changeName(event, cur.id)} 
            delete={(event) => this.deletePerson(cur.id)} 
        />;
```

This is the code from my Person.js

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log(`[Person component] shouldComponentUpdate()`);
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log(nextProps);
        console.log(nextProps.name !== this.props.name || nextProps.age !== this.props.age || nextProps.job !== this.props.job);
        console.log(nextProps.delete !== this.props.delete);
        console.log(`------------------------`);
        console.log(this.props.delete);
        console.log(nextProps.delete);
        return nextProps !== this.props;
    }
```

The

```
console.log(nextProps.name !== this.props.name || nextProps.age !== this.props.age || nextProps.job !== this.props.job);
            console.log(nextProps.delete !== this.props.delete);
```

Returns false as expected, but the `console.log(nextProps.delete !== this.props.delete);` always returns true even though I've deleted all the codes in `App.js` `deletePerson()` method.

Why is that?

Comment: When you say you've " deleted all the codes in App.js deletePerson() method" what does that look like?

Comment: Like this deletePerson = (id) => { }

Comment: I wonder if by using the inline arrow function (i.e. `(event) => this.deletePerson(cur.id)`), a new function object is created each time? Have you tried assigning that function to a variable outside of `render()`?

Comment: Hi Matt, please see Chaim Friedman's answer, perhaps it would also help you. You are right, using arrow function in render() method always returns a new function object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a function like so `() => someFunc()` you are essentially creating a new function on each render. So while the function still does the same thing, in memory its actually a new function.

I would recommend giving [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36) article a quick read thru to see more details about this issue and some solutions.

A common case where passing a new function is the go to, is when the function requires some sort of argument to be passed in to it, for example, an id to know which item to delete. A common solution is to pass the `id` as a prop down to the component along with the function. It would look a little something like this.

```
<Component 
  id={id}
  delete={deleteFunc}
/>

function Component(props) {

  const deleteItem() {
    props.delete(props.id);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={deleteItem}>
      Delete
    </button>
  );
}
```

In this case, the function will always be the same, and we can still have the function accept the arguments it requires.

Comment: Its highlighted in the article I linked, but I will update my answer to include this piece of info with an example.

Comment: Why are you checking the `delete` prop in `shouldComponentUpdate`? Can you just check the other props that actually affect the rendered output of your component?

Comment: Ideally you don't really want to index in to your props to check each item against itself,  because this can lead to a slower check than simply checking whether the old props are the same as the new ones as a whole.